# How to add new span tag on before or after existing span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add new span tag on before or after existing span tag. I know the existing span tag id.

```
<span id="span1">oldtext</span> some para text...
```

need output like below

```
<span id="span1">text</span><span id="span2">newcontent</span> some para text...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `before()` or `.after()` jQuery methods.

```
$('#span1').after('<span id="span2">newcontent</span>");
```

or a better approach,

```
var $span = $('<span>',
              { 'id' : 'span2' , 
               'text': 'Newcontent'})
$('#span1').after($span);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbrgup61/)**

Answer (score -2):

Following line appends one more span tag before existing tag.
$("#span1").prepend("newcontent");